# Check if an API service is down or not in angular

Tags: angular

I'm building an app in which data gets saved, when Web API service goes down need to save in localstorage or IndexDB and once after Web API service comes live then read data from cache and send to API service for CRUD operation.

What should I use? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either poll the service or check the status of API.

```
this.myService.myMethod().subscribe(response => {
if(response.status === 0) console.log("Service is down")});
```